# Apply Flask MethodView decorator just for some methods

Tags: python, flask, view, python-decorators

I was wondering if there is any way that I can use a decorator just for some methods from my class, for example in the following code I want `token_required` to decorate all methods excepting the POST, how could I possibly achieve that?

```
class UserAPI(MethodView):
    def token_required(view_method):
        @wraps(view_method)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            token = None

            if 'token' in request.headers:
                token = request.headers['token']

            if not token:
                return "no token"

            return view_method(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorated

    decorators = [token_required]

    def get(self, user_id):
        if user_id is None:
            # return a list of users
            return "no user id"
        else:
            # expose a single user
            return "user id"

    def post(self):
        # create a new user
        return "create new user"

    def delete(self, user_id):
        # delete a single user
        return "delete user id"

    def put(self, user_id):
        # update a single user
        return "update user id"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a few ways.

**1)** Add condition on `request method` into `decorator`:

```
@wraps(view_method)
def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         # skip token processing - just result of view method 
         return view_method(*args, **kwargs)
     token = None # etc... (your code)
```

**2)** Сreate a universal `decorator` for any point and use him without `decorators` property.

```
from functools import wraps

def token_required():
    def _token_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def __token_required(*args, **kwargs):
            token = None
            if 'token' in request.headers:
                token = request.headers['token']

            if not token:
                return "no token"

            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return __token_required
    return _token_required
```

Just add to specific endpoint when token is required:

```
@token_required()
def get(self, user_id):
    ...
```

Hope this helps.